# Append each value in a DataFrame to a np vector, grouping by column

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create a list, which will be fed as input to the neural network of a Deep Reinforcement Learning model.

*What I would like to achieve:*
This list should have the properties of this code's output

```
vec = []
lines = open("data/" + "GSPC" + ".csv", "r").read().splitlines()
for line in lines[1:]:
        vec.append(float(line.split(",")[4]))
```

i.e. just a list of values like this [enter image description here][1]

The original dataframe looks like:

```
Out[0]: 
        Close     sma15
0    1.26420  1.263037
1    1.26465  1.263193
2    1.26430  1.263350
3    1.26450  1.263533
```

but by using df.transpose() i obtained the following:

```
           0         1        2        3          
Close  1.264200  1.264650  1.26430  1.26450
sma15  1.263037  1.263193  1.26335  1.263533
```

from here I would like to obtain a list grouped by column, of the type:

```
[1.264200, 1.263037, 1.264650, 1.263193, 1.26430, 1.26335, 1.26450, 1.263533]
```

I tried 
`x = np.array(df.values.tolist(), dtype = np.float32).reshape(1,-1)`

but this gives me a float with 1 row and 6 columns, how could I achieve a result that has the properties I am looking for?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you just want a flattened version of the DataFrame's values. That can be done simply with the `ndarray.flatten()` method rather than reshaping it.

```
# Creating your DataFrame object
a = [[1.26420, 1.263037],
     [1.26465, 1.263193],
     [1.26430, 1.263350],
     [1.26450, 1.263533]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Close', 'sma15'])

df.values.flatten()
```

This gives `array([1.2642, 1.263037, 1.26465, 1.263193, 1.2643, 1.26335, 1.2645, 1.263533])` as is (presumably) desired.

PS: I am not sure why you have not included the last row of the DataFrame as the output of your transpose operation. Is that an error?

Comment: Spot on! That's exactly what I was looking for, Thank you very much. Also, yes not including the last row was an accident.